# Command binding in WPF MVM

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF project. In that I have 3 views and one viewmodel.

1.View 1.Xaml, View1viewmodel.cs
2.View 2.Xaml
3.View 3.Xaml

View 3 is referred in view 2 like below

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <local:FeatureView x:Name="View3" Margin="0,5,5,0" Visibility="{Binding 
        IsFeatureView,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

and View2 is referred in view 1 like below

```
<StackPanel>
    <local:ProjectConfigurations x:Name="View2" />
<StackPanel/>
```

Datacontext in defined in View1

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:View1ViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
```

now i need to command bind a check box control of View 3. the property is defined in View1ViewModel.but am unable to achieve that, please any one guide me to achieve this

Comment: Sorry but can you change the format of your question a little bit, Your explanation is very confusing

Comment: command binding is not working in my project. I have 3 different view.xaml, and one commaon viewmodel.cs.view3 is local 2 view2 . view 2 is local 2 view 1. how to apply command binding to view 3. i need to use the viewmodel.cs of view1.

Comment: Can you check the Output tab in Visual Studio and see if any Binding error appears there? It could be helpful to know the exact error

Comment: Also, does the Visibility binding in FeatureView work correctly? Have you checked you're not changing the DataContext at some point in the visual tree? (some WPF tool like Snoop would be helpful to check that)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use a [`RelativeSource Binding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.relativesource(v=vs.110).aspx) to access the property from the view model.

In view 3:

```
<Checkbox Content="{Binding DataContext.PropertyInViewModel, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type YourPrefix:View1}}}"
```

Comment: I have tried relative source binding it doesn't work for view 3. if i use the same in view 2 means its working. so am confused

Comment: If view3 is in view2 and view2 in is view1, then a `RelativeSource Binding` *will* work, so perhaps you should try again. Don't forget to include `DataContext.` in the `Binding Path` as I have above.

Comment: I have used this in view 3                                                                                                Command="{Binding DataContext.FeatureChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=Features}"/> is this correct?